# Is it possible to check for NaN in Code.org AppLab?

Tags: nan, code.org

I have a coin flip simulator on Code.org AppLab. (Just to be clear, it's in JavaScript.) There's a text input box where the user enters the number of desired flips, then clicks a button below it. I want this code to check if the input is not a number, so I used isNaN...

```
onEvent("button2","click",function(){

if (getNumber("text_input1") == isNaN) {

    setText("text_area1","Please enter an integer.");
  } else {
    while ((flipCt < Math.abs(getNumber("text_input1")))) {
    flipVal = randomNumber(0, 1);
    flipCt++;
    if (flipVal == 1) {
        headcount++;
        headstreak++;
        if (headstreak > hscount) {
          hscount = headstreak;
        }
        tailstreak = 0;
      } else {
        tailcount++;
        tailstreak++;
        if (tailstreak > tscount) {
          tscount = tailstreak;
        }
        headstreak = 0;
      }
    }
    setText("VERY LONG LINE OF CODE, so I deleted it for this post."));
  }
});
```

So... line 2 is my problem. I can't seem to get it to correctly check for NaN - it always skips to the "else" part and makes it 0 if I put in a non-number value. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of isNan is wrong. You need to use isNaN(getNumber("text_input1")) . if its Nan it returns true else false

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```js
onEvent("button2","click",function(){

if (!getNumber("text_input1").includes(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) { /// make sure to put the "!"

    setText("text_area1","Please enter an integer.");
  } else {
    while ((flipCt < Math.abs(getNumber("text_input1")))) {
    flipVal = randomNumber(0, 1);
    flipCt++;
    if (flipVal == 1) {
        headcount++;
        headstreak++;
        if (headstreak > hscount) {
          hscount = headstreak;
        }
        tailstreak = 0;
      } else {
        tailcount++;
        tailstreak++;
        if (tailstreak > tscount) {
          tscount = tailstreak;
        }
        headstreak = 0;
      }
    }
    setText("VERY LONG LINE OF CODE, so I deleted it for this post."));
  }
});
```

This will have it check to see if there are not any numbers within text_input1. Otherwise, it will run the rest of your code.